# How to forward https with php POST to a different domain via DNS?

Tags: apache, redirect, mod-rewrite, dns

I'm in the middle of updating a domain name which is currently using HTTPS and has an API that many users are connecting to daily.

What I need to do, is basically reroute all that traffic via DNS/the new server to the new domain name.

EG

Currently users are hitting: https://olddomain.com/api and we are now using https://newdomain.com/api so I need all calls from https://olddomain.com/api to be redirect, with php POST data intact to https://newdomain.com/api

CNAME doesn't seem to redirect it with post data, and it fails the API call. The CNAME is for olddomain.com pointing to newdomain.com, with apache2 mod rewrites which should take care of the redirects, if you navigate to olddomain.com it does forward to newdomain.com but the POST data does not go with it for some reason. The new server has both the old and new domain SSL certs, so that should be valid.

This is what my 000-default looks like in /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName newdomain.com
    ServerAlias newdomain.com

    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com
    RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

    DocumentRoot /var/www
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks
            AllowOverride ALL
    </Directory>
    <Directory /var/www/>
            Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride ALL
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
    <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName newdomain.com
        SSLEngine on
        SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/newdomain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/newdomain.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl_bundle.crt
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
        ServerName olddomain.com
        ServerAlias www.olddomain.com
        RewriteEngine on
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^olddomain.com
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]
        RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.olddomain.com
        RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]

        SSLEngine on
        SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/certs/olddomain.com.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/private/olddomain.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/apache2/ssl/ssl_bundle.crt
        DocumentRoot /var/www/
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the HTTP status 307 (Temporary redirect) instead of 301? According to the [W3C's HTTP/1.1 Status Codes Definitions](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html), this method would allow you to preserve the original HTTP method (and therefore its associated body in case of a POST) of the redirected request, although the standards also mandates that the user agent asks confirmation from the user in case of a non-GET and non-HEAD.

eg., in you Apache configuration file, try to replace lines like:

**RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=301]**

by:

**RewriteRule ^/(.*)$ https://newdomain.com/$1 [L,R=307]**

Note that some user agents have been reported not to be conforming to the standard regarding the HTTP 307 status (eg. not asking user confirmation), while some others do not understand it at all. So I suggest to test it carefully with the browsers you target if you choose to use this method and look for fallback mechanisms if needed.

Comment: This also has the same effect and doesn't seem to work either.